# my battery charge indicator is continually flashing on and off

Tags: battery, charging

My battery charge indicator (the screen info saying % full), flashes on/off/on/off, etc. sometimes.

I've switched the battery to a spare to see if that helps but it didn't.

When it does happen, this seems to happen at all the different wall sockets where I am.  It happens a lot in cafe's.... perhaps not surprising... but also in my office building which seems pretty solid for such business services.

The only place it doesn't happen is at home.

My original theory was that it was due to too many people using the same circuit and reducing the amps too much.  However the more places I see this behavior in, the less I think it is likely.

Any idea how to address this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a different cord/charger?

It seems as if it isn't related to a specific location, so I would suspect that the cable has gone bad.

Comment: This did not really work for me, I even tried a USB cable connected to my mac.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the voltage supplied is too low for your tab to boot up with a completely drained battery. My suggestion is to try using original tab chargers or try charging your tab with a car charger. Using a JBL tab charger might work.

Answer (score 0):

Mine does this ONLY when i use it in the garage, and I have an overloaded power strip, too many things plugged-into one outlet. It's not getting full power perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Flashing battery indicator can mean that the battery is overheated

Comment: Documentation anywhere to support this?

Answer (score 0):

Was not the cable in my case. Turned out to be the ac to USB adapter from the wall. Switched my OEM ac to USB adapter yesterday to an apple ac to USB is when my problem happened today, switched back to OEM shipped with my tablet and everything is back to normal.

Hope this helps some of you.

Answer (score -3):

This may be a symptom of NSA eavesdropping. Another sign of NSA eavesdropping on your calls is quick battery drain within 1-2 minutes. I Suspect being monitored as Im constantly questioned each time I come into the US. Mail being redirected and opened, then delivered, etc. Good luck

http://www.iiiweb.net/blog/5-signs-a-spy-might-have-control-of-your-mobile-phone/